# Download file from sftp to airflow

Tags: python, airflow

How can I change this S3Hook into SSHook or SFTPHook?

```
def download_csv_from_s3 (key: str, bucket_name: str, local_path: str) -> str:
    hook = S3Hook("conn-name")
    file_name = hook.download_file(
        key=key,
        bucket_name=bucket_name,
        local_path=local_path)
    return file_name
```

I want to download files from sftp and I don't know how to define the connection.

Answer (score 1):

For sftp connection, you have two options to authenticate:

- with login and password

  ```
  host: <your sftp host>
  login: <sftp user>
  password: <sftp password>
  ```
- with a private key

  ```
  host: <your sftp host>
  extra: {
     "private_key": "<private key as string>"
  }
  ```

  or

  ```
  host: <your sftp host>
  extra: {
     "key_file": "<path to your private key file>"
  }
  ```

You can create the connection via the UI or the CLI, exporting the environment variable or by python API.

For the sftp hook:

```py
sftp_hook = SFTPHook(ssh_conn_id='<sftp connection id>')
# download a file
sftp_hook.retrieve_file('<remote filepath>', '<local filepat>')
# upload a file
sftp_hook.store_file('<remote filepath>', '<local filepat>', confirm=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Airflow hooks:

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-ssh/stable/_api/airflow/providers/ssh/hooks/ssh/index.html

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-sftp/stable/_api/airflow/providers/sftp/hooks/sftp/index.html